# Implicit sentence target

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is the following correct English?

```
The next train is the Stratford?
```

I like the construction of this sentence because it avoids repeating the word "train", but I am unsure if it is a valid construction.

Comment: If someone said 'The next train is **the** Stratford,' I would jump to the conclusion that I had heard, 'The next train is **to** Stratford,' because that is grammatical, informative and terse. I often mishear and edit.

Comment: The real announcement in London is "The next train is for Stratford", but the "for" is poorly enunciated, hence my original mishearing. I liked the implicit double-use of "train" in the misheard version.

Comment: I must try and build neckstrain into into the conversation on a train:
First hard of hearing dude says, "Brrrrr, it's windy!" Second one says, "No...it's Thursday." Third one says "Don't mind if I do."

Comment: Amtrak, the US national passenger rail service, names its trains.  So you might hear "The next train is the *Crescent*" or "The next train is the *Vermonter*," but none is directly named for a station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid construction. What you are seeing is an example of ellipsis, which is acceptable when the context and meaning are understood (as it is in this sentence, in my opinion).

> In linguistics, ellipsis (from the Greek: ἔλλειψις, élleipsis, "omission") or elliptical construction refers to the omission from a clause of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the remaining elements. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)))

Check out the article [*Noun Ellipsis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_ellipsis) for more details and many examples.

===

EDIT: By request in the comments below, I am including additional evidence for this answer, below.

> In conversation and writing that imitates speech, unstressed pronouns and other functional items are frequently ellipted, as they are recoverable from the interactional context. (Downing, Angela. *English Grammar: A University Course*. Section 29.5.2 Situational Ellipsis. 2014)
>
> English has broadly three types of ellipsis: nominal, verbal and clausal. Nominal ellipsis often involves omission of a noun headword: (2.20) Nelly liked the green tiles; myself I preferred the blue. (McCarthy, Michael. *Discourse Analysis for Language Teachers.* Section 2.2.2 Ellipsis and Substitution, page 43. Cambridge University Press, 1991.)
>
> Ellipsis is the omission of one or more words from a sentence, where they are unnecessary because they have already been mentioned. Meaning can be understood without these words. Ellipsis is one of the aspects of language that gives text cohesion. ...  An example of nominal ellipsis, where a noun phrase is omitted, is 'as it has the last three ( )' and of verbal ellipsis 'Yes, I have ( )'.  (*Ellipsis*, [TeachingEnglish.org.uk](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/ellipsis))
>
> The nature of Ellipsis refers to the omission of elements normally required by the grammar which the speaker/writer assumes are obvious from the context. So, the elliptical information usually has appeared previously or can be inferred from the context of sentence, and when they are left out, the sentence can still be understood. ... Nominal ellipsis refers to ellipsis within the nominal phrase, including the omission of the noun, the omission of the noun plus part of its Modifiers, and the omission of the whole nominal phrase. For example: A: Here are my two white scarves; B: I used to have three. (*Ellipsis*, [XiamenWriting](https://xiamenwriting.wikispaces.com/Ellipsis))

I would like to draw attention to the example provided by *Discourse Analysis for Language Teachers*:

> Nelly liked the green tiles; myself I preferred the blue.

In this example, it's clear from the context that the speaker is referring to blue *tiles*. The speaker includes the article and an adjectives, but omits the noun, because in this example of situational ellipsis, the noun can be inferred from context to be the same as the noun following "the green" in the first clause.

This example parallels our train example:

> The next train is the Stratford.

This is an ellipsis of "The next train is the Stratford (train)." Here, again, we see parallel construction of noun phrases, using article-adjective-noun structure: *the next train* / *the Stratford train*. Thus, the word *train* can be readily understood.

A reader in the comments implied that it would be more clear if the sentence were:

> The next train is the Stratford to Bristol.

That may be true, if the trains were named by line ("...the Stratford line train heading towards Bristol") or origin station ("...the train originated in Stratford and bound for Bristol"). Without knowing the details of this train system, however, it's just as plausible that the *destination* is Stratford. in this case, the meaning of the sentence could validly be:

> The next train is the (train bound for) Stratford.

This does present some ambiguity (without knowing the details of the train system in question, it's unclear whether the train is going to or from Stratford). In either event, however, we know that we are talking about a train, and the train is characterized by the city name. So this is enough information to determine the ellipted/omitted noun.

The takeaway from these sources and examples is that nominal ellipsis is considered valid in English, particularly for (but limited to) informal or verbal speech where the omitted text is clear.

One final note: You will note the absence of NGrams here. This is not by accident. NGrams are not particularly helpful when showing ellipsis, particularly when the ellipted word is the at the end of the phrase. Searching for "The next train is the Stratford" *should* also produce sentences without the ellipsis, i.e. "the next train is the Stratford train." When no data is returned for the ellipted sentence, we can't make any judgments one way or the other; both data examples are unavailable. One thing that we could try is to search for alternatives, but "the train to stratford,the stratford train,the train from stratford" all produce no results either. Apparently, people just don't talk about trains pertaining to Stratford much, at least in the corpus that Google is using for its NGram engine. We could do some searching for other cities and so forth, but the fundamental point holds: finding very specific examples of verbal ellipsis in a books corpus is difficult.

Comment: It sounds as natural as 'This is valid construction.' 'The next train is the Stratford to Bristol' / 'The next train is the 18:35 to Bath' / 'The next train is the one to (or for) Birmingham' / 'The next train is the Chennai Express' are idiomatic; 'The next train is the Bristol one' and 'The next train is the Bristol train' are acceptable. NOT 'The next train is the Stratford'.

Comment: @Edwin-Ashworth: Grammatically and semantically, the difference between "The next train is the Stratford" and "The next train is the Stratford to Bristol" appears minimal. In my mind, they are either both valid (my opinion) or both invalid. Perhaps the OP example sounds different to your ear and mine due to regional differences?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Nonsense. This is done all the time in English and is perfectly acceptable as a shorthand naming convention. How about U.S.S. Yorktown? Are you going to say that we always have to have "aircraft carrier" in the sentence along the lines of "U.S.S. Yorktown aircraft carrier" or "the aircraft carrier known as the U.S.S. Yorktown sailed into battle"?

Comment: @Nonnal Please support your answer with some evidence then. I checked fairly extensively on the internet before I posted to give what my many years as an Anglophone strongly suggested as being the actual situation.  Did you? You need to consider pragmatics in addition to grammar and semantics.

Comment: @Languagemaven Are you seriously suggesting that 'The Yorktown arrives tomorrow' and 'The London arrives at 4:30' are equally idiomatic? Deletions are common, but idiosyncratic

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth Yep. ellipsis is a permissible technique to use as a shorthand. It's universal. "Idiosyncratics" are irrelevant.

Comment: @Languagemaven This example is non-standard. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Yorktown+arrived%2Cthe+Crewe+arrived&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Yorktown%20arrived%3B%2Cc0) flatline for 'the Crewe arrived', and even though that for 'the London arrived' is not a flatline, all the references seem to be to the ship. Even OP now seems to say that he has never heard the expression. There is no 'elide at will' licence in English. If one wants to sound unnatural, though, one will doubtless not be arrested.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth -- LMAO. Perhaps if you had done your "research" as you claimed, you'd realize that "elide" is the verb form of the noun "elision," which is not the same thing as "ellipsis" and is not at issue in this question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision

Comment: (1)  _Elide_: 'It's a technical term in linguistics, usually in phonetics and phonology; I've also seen it used occasionally in syntax, speaking of such phenonema as Conversational Deletion, Conjunction Reduction, To-Deletion, To Be-Deletion, or That-Deletion, etc.' [John Lawler]. It's been used on ELU quite a few times. (2) I'm not sure how you can reconcile 'Dictionaries, I'd argue, are only arbiters of usage' with a Wikipedia endorsement. // You haven't addressed the point I make about the 'The next train is the Stratford' etc usage being almost non-existent on the internet.

Comment: ... (3) I consider 'Nonsense' and 'LMAO' to be unnecessarily confrontational and will flag any further abuse.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As requested in your comment above ("Please support your answer with some evidence then"), I have updated my answer with additional evidence in support of my assertion that this is valid nominal ellipsis. // Respectfully, it's still unclear to me why you assert that "The next train is the Stratford" is "not acceptable" but that "The next train is the Stratford to Bristol" is idiomatic and hence acceptable. I love to learn, though, and if can offer evidence yourself I'd genuinely appreciate seeing it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, and in answer to your question ("I checked fairly extensively on the internet before I posted to give what my many years as an Anglophone strongly suggested as being the actual situation. Did you?"): Yes I did. And, for the record, I too have "many years an an Anglophone," although I usually just call myself a native English speaker with a longstanding love for learning about grammar.

Comment: The dedicated [Wickipedia article on Noun Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_ellipsis) has 'An important aspect of N-ellipsis concerns the material that can (and cannot) be elided.' This indicates that nouns cannot be acceptably dropped at will. Even one of your quotes has 'Ellipsis is the omission of one or more words from a sentence, where they are unnecessary because they have already been mentioned.' I wouldn't go that far, but it obviously indicates that there are restrictions. You can easily drop 'minutes' in five minutes to four, but 'four to four' sounds unnatural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I concur with your take that ellipsis can't be done "at will" and that there are restrictions. When the ellipted word is unclear and not previously mentioned, then we are transitioning to inference versus ellipsis.

Comment: There are further restrictions. 'Minutes' is very easily recovered in 'five to ten' etc, but 'four to ten' is never used. I'm maintaining that 'The Wigan is here' sounds outlandish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32013/discussion-between-nonnal-and-edwin-ashworth).